# How to have Xcode not care about errors coming back from a custom script (/dev/null)?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, shell, scripting-bridge

I have a custom script in Xcode which returns an error, but suppose I don't care. Xcode doesn't care about /dev/null and won't compile

```
sdef "$INPUT_FILE_PATH" | sdp -fh -o "$DERIVED_FILES_DIR" 
--basename "$INPUT_FILE_BASE" 
--bundleid `defaults read "$INPUT_FILE_PATH/Contents/Info" CFBundleIdentifier`
```

It's basically for generating a .h file based on Apple Script Definitions, and it went all fine up until a recent OS X update.

In the terminal, all I have to so is end this command with

```
2>/dev/null
```

and no error is returned. Whatever I try with 2> or just > or even &> doesn't work in Xcode, it will always return me an error.

```
/bin/sh -c "sdef \"$INPUT_FILE_PATH\" | sdp -fh -o \"$DERIVED_FILES_DIR\" 
--basename \"$INPUT_FILE_BASE\" --bundleid `defaults read
\"$INPUT_FILE_PATH/Contents/Info\" CFBundleIdentifier` 2> /dev/null"

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: FYI, it doesn't solve the *real* problem, but I decided to fix the code of the "bad definition" file, by doing this: `sdef ... | sed 's/<contents name="contents"/<contents name="contents" code="ctnt"/g' | sep ...` so I'm basically doing a search and replace which makes "sdef | sdp" not returning an error anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Appending 2>/dev/null does not prevent the error status being returned by the sdef command, it just hides the error message.

Replace it with

```
|| echo "Failed".
```

If the sdef fails, the second part of the command is exited, and the echo should not report a bad status.

Comment: Nope. That won't help, because in this case, no output files (here `$(DERIVED_FILES_DIR)/$(INPUT_FILE_BASE).h`) would be generated, and thus the compiler will break later in my project. But that's a good tip anyways.